# How to change the thickness & colour of the <hr> tag?

Tags: html, css, colors, thickness

I can see this has been answered but i've tried all of the solutions yet still have a barely visable HR.

What am I doing wrong?

```
hr {
    background-color: dimgrey;
    color: dimgrey;
    border: solid 2px dimgrey;
    height: 5px;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Is your styling being overwritten? (for example bootstrap)

Comment: Please include an example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure what you consider barely visible but a 5px height is pretty visible. :)

Make sure that you are defining this css after other css which might be overwriting this rule.

Or, use !important to give this rule precedence:

```
hr {
    background-color: dimgrey !important;
    color: dimgrey !important;
    border: solid 2px dimgrey !important;
    height: 5px !important;
    width: 1000px !important;
}
```

Another approach is to define a custom class for this style:

```
.bigHr {
    background-color: dimgrey !important;
    color: dimgrey !important;
    border: solid 2px dimgrey !important;
    height: 5px !important;
    width: 1000px !important;
}
```

... and then use that class when you want this style:

```
<hr class="bigHr">
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the Bootstrap framework that was overwriting the styling!

Comment: Thanks , it was exactly what  I wanted.

Comment: Is there any bootstrap 4 class available to increase the thickness of <hr /> tag ?